# How do I interpret brute force in algorithm creation instructions?

Tags: c, algorithm

My hangup with the following problem is interpreting what is meant by  brute-forceness, and I believe I could design the code for this problem, if I simply knew what it was asking. :/

Here are the instructions:

> [15 marks] What kind of solutions a programmer might come up with for the problem of making change in Assignment 3, if he/she does not
>   know greedy algorithms at all? One possible way of solving this
>   problem is exhaustive search, or the brute-force approach. In this
>   approach, we test all possible answers, and compare those that are
>   correct solutions to the given problem, in order to find the optimal
>   answer.
>
> In particular, for the problem of marking change, given a cash
>   amount in cents, we can first find out for any way of making change
>   correctly (NOT necessarily using as few coins as possible), the
>   maximum numbers of toonies, loonies, etc. that we can use. We can then
>   perform a six-level loop to iterate through all possibles combinations
>   of coins, using the maximum numbers computed before as the upper bound
>   for the corre- sponding coins in any solution. More precisely, in the
>   outermost loop, we iterator the solutions that use 1 toonie, 2
>   toonies, ..., the maximum number of toonies computed. In the second
>   outermost loop, we iterate the solutions that use 1 loonie, 2 loonies,
>   ..., the maximum number of loonies computed (the number of toonies in
>   these solutions is determined in the outermost loop), and so on. In
>   the innermost loop, for each solution, we check whether it is a
>   correct solution for the given cash amount. If it is, then we check
>   whether it uses fewer coins than all the correct solutions that we
>   have seen so far.
>
> For example, if the cash amount is 200, then we can
>   use at most 1 toonie, 2 loonies, 8 quarters, 20 dimes, 40 nickels and
>   200 pennies in any solution. We then check the following solutions
>   (each solution contains 6 numbers that are the numbers of coins of
>   eachtypeused,startingfromtoonies):
>   0,0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0,1;0,0,0,0,0,2; ..., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200; 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
>   200; 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1; .... In this particular
>   example, any solution that we test should use no more than 1 toonie, 2
>   loonies, 8 quarters, 20 dimes, 40 nickels and 200 pennies.

What's it mean by this brute-forceness? I understand how it's finding the maximum number possible for each kind of coin, but how is this then used to solve the numbers of each kind of coin the person should get?

Comment: I think it means that aside from computing the maximum number of each coin, it doesn't do anything more intelligent than try every possible combination of coin values, whether or not they add up to the correct amount, and then test whether each combination both adds up to the right amount and is better than any previous combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brute force solution means trying all possible solutions. For many problems, it's very expensive to try all solutions. It's called brute force, because it doesn't require any special insight into the problem.

For example, if you were picking a lock, then a brute force solution might be to make every key possible, and try them all. Naturally, this would take a long time.

You can read more in this wikipedia article about [brute force search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).

Without the original problem description from your assignment, it's hard to describe the brute force solution in detail - but I'll try. For 200 cash, the general procedure is to generate all possible combinations of coins up to 200 cash, and check them for correctness.

If your problem is a yes/no problem (where solutions either succeed or they don't), and you only need one answer. you could stop once you've found a solution. If your problem involves some sort of score (for example, the travelling salesman problem), and you want the best answer, a brute force search would need to try all solutions to be certain it has the best answer.

You would generally apply brute force to a specific instance of the problem - say your particular instance of the problem is "for 200 cash", then you generate all possible solutions to 200 cash only. Next time, when your problem is for "10 cash" then you'd generate and test all solutions to the 10 cash problem. Remember that brute force isn't meant to be an efficient way of generating a solution - but for problems that you **can** brute force, you can guarantee that you've found the best answer once the brute forcing completes.

Note that most problems have more efficient ways of generating optimal solutions (eg branch-and-bound would outperform brute force for travelling salesman type problems).

---

The last paragraph is saying that if you know the maximum amount of cash, you can make sure you don't generate or test solutions that would give you more than 200 cash. A simple way to do that is to work out how many loonies there are in 200 cash, and then not generate any solutions that use any more than that number.

A better way to bound your generation of solutions is to set numbers for progressively smaller coins, to ensure that you always add up to the right amount of cash:

```
 for(0 to (cash % valueof(toonies)) as t) {
   set cash_after_toonies to be (cash - valueof(t * toonies))

   for(0 to (cash_after_toonies % valueof(loonies)) as l) {
     set cash_after_loonies to be (cash_after_toonies - valueof(l * loonies))

     for(0 to (cash_after_loonies % valueof(quarters)) as q) {
       set cash_after_quarters to be (cash_after_loonies - valueof(q * quarters)

       for(0 to (cash_after_quarters % valueof(dimes)) as d) {
         set cash_after_dimes to be (cash_after_quarters - valueof(d * dimes))

         for(0 to (cash_after_dimes % valueof(nickels)) as n) {          
            set cash_after_nickels to be (cash_after_dimes - valueof(n * nickels))

            set p = cash_after_nickels in pennies
            check_for_correctness(l,t,q,d,n,p);
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, that explains a lot. But I'm still a little confused as to how I would apply it in this case. I could figure out I need 200 pennies if it's 200¢ (and the same for every other coin) but turning that into the most efficient solution is a little hard to wrap my mind around.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit - does that make things clearer?

Comment: Thanks, I believe so. So, if I put in 200 (obviously it has to work for any amount of coins in the end, but 200 for example) it would generate every possible combination, and then see which one uses less coins to accomplish this, and then output that set of numbers?

Comment: I've added a bit of psuedocode that hopefully helps explain the last paragraph in the question a bit.

Comment: Note that you'll have to check it for descending value of coins - I don't speak loony tunes :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely helped, even if you don't speak Canadian. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A brute force approach attempts all possible solutions to see which are correct. For example cracking a password by brute force would be trying AAAAAA, AAAAAB, ... and so on .

In your example he is asking you to try all combinations of possible coins to get the right change solution. The only tricky part is he is saying that you should never have more of any one coin than if change was made using only that coin.

For example you don't need to try (2 toonies, .....) on making change for a 200cent bill since you know there can be at most 1 toonie.

Each combination of coins can then be checked to see if it is the correct amount of change, and you can count the number of coins to find which combination uses the least.